# Syntatic sugar for a for-loop counter

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any syntatic sugar for a loop used just to count iterations? For example

```
int count = randomNumber;
List<X> objectXList = new List<X>();

//Add a new object to objectXList count times
//
for(int i=0; i<count ; i++)
{
    objectXList.Add(new X());
}
```

Comment: So what are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enumerable.Range returns a specified number of integers starting at a given value.  In your case Enumerable.Range starting at 0 would work, for a length `count`.

```
Enumerable.Range(0, count).ToList().ForEach(i => objectXList.Add(new X()));
```

or maybe better yet, for all of the micro-optimizers out there:

```
var objectXList = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => new X()).ToList();
```